# Realmで入力済みデータを設定，更新する方法

Tags: android, realm

Realmを利用し，ゲーム履歴管理アプリを作成しようとしています．
具体的には

```
public class MapArea extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public String name;
}
```

のようなマップ情報を予め持ち

```
public class Play extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public Date date;
    public MapArea mapArea;
}
```

のようなプレイ情報を記録したいと考えています．

ここで，マップ情報は予め入力済みのレコードを使用したいのですが，アプリのアップデート時にマップを追加する可能性があります．
`RealmConfiguration.Builder.assetFile()`により初期データをassetsよりコピーすることができることは判明したのですが，マップ追加時にデータを追従させる方法がわかりませんでした．

Realmデータベースに対し入力済みデータを与え，かつそれをアプリアップデート時に更新するにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RealmConfiguration.Builder.assetFile()
```

は初期化時のデータ挿入に利用できそうですが、アップデート時には難しそうです。

そこで、「入力済みデータ」はjsonやcsvで用意し、アプリアップデート時に

```
realm.executeTransaction()
```

などで追記や更新処理をするのが良いと思います。

他にもrealmならではの手法があるかもしれませんが、最低限実現可能な方法だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

他には、アプリ更新でMapAreaに追加があった場合はRealmのスキーマバージョンをインクリメントしてしまう方法もあるかと思います。

こうすることでマイグレーション処理が走るので、その中で増えた分のMapAreaをinsertすることができます。

Answer (score 0):

例えばversionCodeをどこかに保持しておいてアプリ起動の度にアプリのversionCodeと比較し、アプリのアップデートを検知して追加更新処理をするのはどうでしょうか。